# RxSwift - fetch every item on the list

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a method that receives `[Int]`, which are **ids** of some **Items**.

I'd like to go through this list and download every **Item** using another method that returns/download `Observable<Item>` to finally return an `Observable<[Item]>` in this very same function.

How can I do this using RxSwift/RxCocoa operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an easy one! There's a couple of sneaky protocol extensions for arrays of observables built into the library.

```
list.map { Int->Observable<Item> in
    downloadItem($0)
}
.zip { $0 }
```